# how to create an xml from oracle command in c#

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I have a below query in C# getting data from oracle

```
 using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
     OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select firstname,secondname,lastname,
age,gender from Members", con))
     OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
    .....
    } 

    }
```

Now from this query i need to create an xml as below. Please help me to know the best way to achieve the same

```
<Root>
<Member>
<Name>
  <firstname>firstname1<firstname>
  <secondname>secondname1<secondname>
  <lastname>lastname<lastname>
</Name>
<age>45</age>
<gender>M</gender>
</Member>
<Member>
<Name>
  <firstname>firstname2<firstname>
  <secondname>secondname2<secondname>
  <lastname>lastname2<lastname>
</Name>
<age>25</age>
<gender>F</gender>
</Member>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

First method .Use `XmlElement,XMLAttributes, XMLForest`... for selected items, for additional information please open link below

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB4994

Second method. You can read query result and after that  try serialize an object to XML